# Error message doesn't appear when user enter invalid number

Tags: c

I have made a simple program which is working and now I want when I enter the number which is "greater then 100 and less then 0" it should show a message of invalid number.

```
int math,eng,phy;
float f,h;
printf("Enter math marks:");
scanf("%d",&math);
if (math<0 && math>100)
{
    printf("You have entered invalid number");
}
printf("Enter eng marks:");
scanf("%d",&eng);
printf("Enter phy marks:");
scanf("%d",&phy);
f=math+eng+phy;
if (f>=90 && h<=100)
{
    printf(" You got A grade\n");
}
h=f/300*100;
printf("Your obtained marks=%f\n",f);
printf("Your  percentage=%f\n",h);
getch();
}
```

Comment: The question is well asked, OP provided code snippet and described his problem, +1.

Comment: Think about the logic you're using carefully in that condition... It's even written down wrong in the question

Comment: `h=f/300*100;` must be placed before `if (f>=90 && h<=100){}` as `h` is not initialized before comparision.

Comment: @Rex Khan: "when I enter the number which is greater then 100 and less then 0"... Can you provide an example of such a number?

Answer (score 5):

You should use `if(math < 0 || math > 100)`... a number cannot be > 100 and < 0 at the same time.

Comment: Unless the programmer is [Schrödinger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger's_cat).

Comment: Depends if you look at it

Answer (score 4):

There isnt such a number which is greater than 100 and smaller then 0.

Greater than 100 = 101, 102, 103, 104

Smaller than 0 = -1, -2, -3

You see? If you want to only allow numbers between 0 and 100 you need:

```
if(x > 0 && x < 100){ /* Right number */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with the program as written.

First, the evaluation of the math grade is checking whether or not the grade is *simultaneously* less than 0 AND more than 100. This is an impossible case and will cause the program to never print the desired message, even when the math grade variable is outside of the desired range.

```
if (math < 0 && math > 100)
    {
        printf("You have entered invalid number");
```

This can be corrected by using a logical || (or) instead of && (and).

```
if (math < 0 || math > 100)
    {
        printf("You have entered invalid number");
```

The remaining problem lies in the fact that only the math grade is checked in this way. A grade checking function could be written to make sure the english and physics grades are also in the proper range.